# Npm install karma hangs on node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, node-gyp

I'm running this on a Windows 7 x64 machine:

```
npm install -g karma
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.0
-
> ws@0.4.32 install C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

After the last line it simply hangs!

I've tried everything i can think of
- uninstall/reinstall node (0.10.32)
- delete the node_packages folder from the user appdata
- checking the builderror.log file (it's empty)
- installing nodex32 and x64, same problem
- waiting :)

What's interesting is that while it's hanged the node.exe process eats up one CPU. I'm not sure if it's really doing something or it's hanged.

Any ideas?

l.e.: it seems it's a problem with node-gyp, as running e.g.

```
node-gyp configure or 
node-gyp rebuild
```

hangs as well with

```
gyp info using node@0.10.32 | win32 | ia32
```

Comment: Same problem now appears on a win8 x64 machine :( Strangely, on two other machines, one win7 x64 and another win8 x64 it works fine.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm experiencing the exact same problem and would love any additional info you have.

Comment: Same thing happens for me on a mac.

Comment: Ditto, hangs on my mac right after ' node-gyp rebuild'

Comment: Occurs on latest OSX here as well.

Comment: Yeah I hate when that happens... whenever I install a  a package dependent on node-gyp (karma or phantomjs) it just chokes up my entire machine. Browser stops working. It takes forever. And it doesn't matter where I run it - natively in OS X, inside Windows VM or a Docker container. How to fix that?

Comment: it seems my problems can be solved by having python installed and using http instead of https for npm. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397883/npm-doesnt-install-any-modules-network-socket-hangs-up

Comment: @Agzam The solution in the question you linked worked in my case! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This might just be related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8566) in WebdriverJS, [which also affects Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2035) and, unfortunately, has not been solved yet. Apparently, a temporary workaround is to [install everything described in this blog post by someone](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/).