# Can't install LESS using node.js

Tags: node.js, less

I am trying to install LESS on a mac. But i keep getting these error messages....

I  am not sure if its a permission issue, and also which directory do I install it?

Any help would be really appreciated.

npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/es/.npm/less/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,

Answer (score 1):

1) Install nodejs setup (node-v5.10.0-x64.exe).

2) Open CMD to step forward.

3) Add bellow code to set nodejs in registry (apply only if registry issues).

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

([NPM doesn't install any modules: network socket hangs up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397883/npm-doesnt-install-any-modules-network-socket-hangs-up))

4) Add bellow code to install autoless (this helps to compile LESS files).

npm install autoless -g

(https://github.com/jgonera/autoless)

5) Now change directory to your style folder (using cd - command line function)

6) Add bellow code to start compile LESS files

autoless --source-map

7) Done, Now you can add compiled CSS file in your HTML.