# npm windows cannot install bower, no errors

Tags: windows, node.js, bower

I am running this command on windows cmd:

```
>npm install -g bower
```

But it hangs on the rotating slash and it rotates to infinite without any result. The proxy is configured correctly and **I can install other npm modules with no problem**. I tried all online suggestion but with no success.

No errors are displayed on console, is there any method to run nmp install in debug  mode?
Any idea?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Davin Tryon it is hanging on this:

```
npm verb addTmpTarball already have metadata; skipping unpack for handlebars@1.3.0
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\handlebars\1.3.0\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\handlebars\1.3.0\package\package.json written
-
```

Comment: `npm config set loglevel verbose --global`

Comment: @DavinTryon  I set it. Now I found it is hanging on the last command up in the edit

Comment: FOUNDED: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397883/npm-doesnt-install-any-modules-network-socket-hangs-up

Comment: @albanx Did u solve the problem ?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I solved it but I do not remember right now, wtf.probably some proxy configuration, set both proxy for http and https to the same value...