# npm install -g ionic not working on windows 7 even I am not on proxy

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

I am kinda stuck here, `npm install -g ionic` not working on my home computer which is windows 7 and i dont have any proxy. i am able to download other packages like `npm install -g gulp`  etc.

Already tried changing as suggested by other guys on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20497988/254662)

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

I am getting bellow error

`npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\node\\\\node.exe" "C:\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.
js" "install" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache first:

```
npm cache clean
```

and then Try to install again

```
npm install -g ionic
```