# How to fix npm socket hang up error

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

When I install following node.js modules using `npm install` command,

***package.json***

```
{
      "name"         : "node-todo",
      "version"      : "0.0.0",
      "description"  : "Simple todo application.",
      "main"         : "server.js",
      "author"       : "Scotch",
      "dependencies" : {
        "express"         : "~4.6.1",
        "mongoose"        : "~3.8.13",
        "morgan"          : "~1.1.1",
        "body-parser"     : "~1.4.3",
        "method-override" : "~2.1.1"
      }
    }
```

the following error is occurred.

[image]

I am a node.js beginner and how to fix this error.

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM doesn't install any modules: network socket hangs up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397883/npm-doesnt-install-any-modules-network-socket-hangs-up)

Comment: Yes, I also tried `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`