# An unhandled exception occurred: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: socket hang up

Tags: angular, package.json, angular9, package-lock.json, angular-upgrade

```js
{
  "name": "ez-new-architecture",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/common": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/braintree-web": "^3.62.2",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^5.0.1",
    "angular-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.3",
    "angular-resize-event": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-sweetalert-service": "^2.0.2",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "braintree-web": "^3.64.2",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.3.2",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^5.3.2",
    "idle-session-timeout": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-fullcalendar": "^5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-plaid-link": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-quill": "^14.2.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I want to update my Angular Project 9 to 14 and i following Angular Update guid [text](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=9.1-14.0)

but there is some problem [After running npm i command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HYjD.png)[after running npx @angular/cli@10 update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K29XB.png)

Package.json file code is

I am trying to Re Create Node_Module and also searching some solution but not getting exact solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM doesn't install any modules: network socket hangs up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397883/npm-doesnt-install-any-modules-network-socket-hangs-up)